# Como alinha um texto dentro de um "input" text HTML

Tags: html, css

Como alinha um texto dentro da "text area" de um input do tipo  text  usando CSS? 
Já tentei text-align mas não funciona bem, o texto fica alinhado na esquerda porem não no topo. Existe algum jeito de alinhar manualmente? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo input no qual estou falando

```
 <input id="menssagemBox" type="text" name="msg" placeholder="teste" class="msgbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

Vc tem que "dar a altura" com `padding-bottom`, e não com `height`.

**OBS:** Só não sei pq vc  quer um `input` com esse layout, não faz sentido já que ele não pode ter mais de uma linha...

```css
#emailBox {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
#emailBox {
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<input id="emailBox" type="email" name="email" placeholder="padding-bottom: 100px;" class="emailBoxClass" />
<input id="emailBox2" type="email" name="email" placeholder="height: 100px;" class="emailBoxClass" />
```

**DICA**

Agora se vc quer um "input" que possa ter mais de uma linha de texto, ai vc tem que usar o `<textarea></textarea>` que diferente do `input` normal tem tag de fechamento e outros atributos globais que vc pode consultar aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

O `<textarea>` vc pode controlar a altura com o atributo `row`, que vai determinar quantas fileiras de linha de texto ele vai ter antes do *scroll*, ou com `height` mesmo se preferir.

```css
#emailBox {
    height: 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<textarea id="emailBox" type="email" name="email" placeholder="height: 100px;" class="emailBoxClass"></textarea>

<textarea id="emailBox2" rows="5" type="email" name="email" placeholder="rows=5" class="emailBoxClass"></textarea>
```

Comment: Acho que ele se confundiu. Ele quer um textarea ao invés de um input text.

Comment: @AlexandrePaiva já vi cada pegunta que preferi responde do jeitinho que perguntaram rss... Mas de qq forma deixei um edit na resposta, valeu o toque